# uploaded file path didnt show on index page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server-2014

when we upload file then that uploaded file path or url didnt show on index page and database

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Route("{SocietyURL}/FormMaster/Create")]
    public ActionResult Create(FormMaster_IVM objFormMaster, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        Int32 SocietyID = Int32.Parse(Session["SocietyID"].ToString());
        objFormMaster.SocietyID = SocietyID;
        FormMasterManager ObjformMasterManager = new FormMasterManager();
        ObjformMasterManager.CreateFormMaster(objFormMaster);
        ObjformMasterManager = null;
        try
        {

            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), FileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
            ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";
            return View();
        }
        catch
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!!";
            return View();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Here is my view

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","FormMaster",FormMethod.Post,new { @enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

```
    <div class="form-row">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FormName, "Form Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FormName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FormName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FormDescription, "Form Description", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FormDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FormDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DocumentAttachment, "Document Attachment", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label", })
            <br />
            <input type="file" name="file" required />          
            </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-theme1" />
        </div>

    </div>
}
```